# AWS CloudFormation custom permissions boundary

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to write your custom permissions boundary policy inside the AWS CloudFormation for AWS Lambda's `LambdaExecutionRole`?

It could be best if I could write all the necessary policies for the `LambdaExecutionRole` inside this code instead of using `!Ref` or `!Sub`.

Please see the `PermissionBoundary` part

(This code doesn't work because of misconfigured permission boundary part)

```yaml
LambdaExecutionRole:
    Description: Creating service role in IAM for AWS Lambda
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'CodeStar-${ProjectId}-Execution${Stage}'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
      PermissionsBoundary: !Sub
        Properties:
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:DescribeLogGroups
              - logs:PutLogEvents
              - xray:Put*
              Effect: Allow
              Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do this. `PermissionsBoundary` **requires ARN** to IAM policy. So first you have to create `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` and then reference it's ARN in `PermissionsBoundary`.

Comment: Do you mean you need to create the ManagedPolicy _outside_ the CloudFormation template, or can it be created inside and referenced?